# Java Object class and multiple inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

It may be very very basic question but didn't find any answer so far, so asking here. By default in java, every class extends **Object** class as far as i know. But again how we are able to extend any other class as multiple inheritance is not possible in java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a difference between Multi-Level vs Multiple Inheritance.

Comment: I think Eran had already answered your question. Just for knowledge sharing this feature of enabling only one class to inheritance is be added to java to avoid a situation what programmers called deadly diamond of death

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A class can't have more than one direct super-class, but it can have multiple ancestors.

For example, `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` which extends `AbstractCollection` which extends `Object`. Even though `ArrayList` has 3 ancestors, it only has one direct super-class - `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 1):

Object is parent class of all classes by default but as soon as you inherit your class from any other class now your class is not direct descendant of Object class any more and hierarchy goes up to the Object class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what Beri said, you can have a situation like this:

```
Class class extends Object implements Interface_1,Interface_2,Interface_3{

}
```

If you are trying to add more to the program, you can always add more classes and import their methods.

It should also be noted that the subclass does not inherit the private variables and methods from the superclass.